# Does gitignore support regexp

Tags: linux, git, repository

How to make `$HOME/.gitignore` understand regexp? Specifically, I want to enable it ignore files modules.builtin and modules.order:

```
modules.\(order\|builtin)
```

This doesn't seem to be picked up when I'm running `git status` What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `gitignore` doesn't support `regex`es, it only supports [unix `fnmatch`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html) style patterns.

You can read more about this [on the git-scm entry for gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

If you have multiple directories/files to ignore, you could try using `modules.*` as a single entry, or two entries as suggested by the other answer.

Comment: Thanks, this probably what I will use: modules.*

Answer (score 1):

No, gitignore does not support full regular expressions. In your particular case, you can just put two lines:

```
modules.order
modules.builtin
```

However, I imagine you want to do a bit more. Gitignore does support *some* pattern matching; you can find the full documentation [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), under "pattern format."